# I have a problem using PDO statement when run sql query for getting existing user its not working

Tags: php, pdo

This is my code and its not giving me result. It is returning me false value while there is data with same credentials inside database. I tried everything but it is not working.

```
private function isUserExist($email_id, $user_id){

  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE `email_id` = ? AND `unique_user_id` = ?");
  $stmt->bindParam(1, $email_id);
  $stmt->bindParam(2, $user_id);
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt->fetch() > 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the point in using two conditions? Isn't email_id or $user id alone enough?

Comment: Before return do print_r($stmt->errorInfo()) , maybe there is a problem.

Comment: @FranCerezo don't do that. It will be embarrassing when your site goes live

Comment: I am talking on local, of course.

Comment: @FranCerezo don't do that either. It would be silly to rewrite your code every time from live to local back and forth.

Comment: @YourCommonSense well, I check that too by using only email_id and its not working.

Comment: What rewriting? This person looks like needs easy advise while developing.

Comment: @FranCerezo every "easy advise" ends up in the production code, so one must be accurate giving them away.

Comment: @vishal so ether there is an error or there is no data to match your criteria. check errors, the input data and your database. Refer to the linked answer for the details.